# Wordpress - Get post meta within 'posts_where' filter

Tags: wordpress, plugins, meta

how do I check if a post meta field equals something in the 'posts_where' filter? I want to skip posts that have a custom field 'my_meta_box_check' set to 'off'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
   global $wpdb;  
   $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'my_meta_box_check' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'off')";
   return $where;
}
```

Comment: it's not displaying any posts now. Even `$where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'my_meta_box_check')";` doesn't work :(

Comment: Whoops - forgot the global reference to the `$wpdb` object.  Also added missing quote. Giver a try now.

Comment: That's odd - above has worked for me in the past.  Can you `var_dump` the `$where` var to see what its contents are (probably won't help grasping at straws here :)

Comment: I already found a different solution. Thanks for your help anyway Pat!

Comment: the global $wpdb; should be inside the function

Comment: Theres a dollar sign missing off the last line `return $where;`